# How to make one job only run after another job passes in a GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

From what I have just ran into, the "needs" line in a gitlab-ci.yml file only checks to see if the job that is defined in the "needs" line is being run - not if it passes or fails.

I ran the below code in my pipeline and the "build-latest" job runs even if the "test-
tag" job fails.

I only want    the "build-latest" job to run if the "test-tag" job passes.

How is this achieved?

```
build-latest:
 stage: publish
 image:
 name: gcr.io/go-containerregistry/crane:debug
 entrypoint: [""]
 rules:
 #- if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "add-latest-tagging"
 when: always
 needs:
    - test-tag
 script:
    - crane auth login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue lies with the fact that you added

```
when: always
```

It is true that since you specified `needs`, the `build-latest` job will need the job `test-tag` to execute first.

After `test-tag` job concluded it will evaluate if it should execute the `build-latest` job.

By adding the `always` clause to the `build-latest` job will force it to execute, even if the `test-tag` fails. Provided `test-tag` job has `at least` concluded

Long story sort, you should remove the when always clause

Answer (score 1):

If you want a job to run only when one or more previous jobs pass, then you want to put it in a [separate stage](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/pipeline_architectures.html#basic-pipelines).

Not sure how you've broken up the jobs without more of the CI file, but assuming:

1. `test-tag` job is in `stage: test`
2. `stage: publish` comes after test

Then it should work the way you want simply by removing the `needs:` option from your `build-latest` job.